# Codeigniter Form Validation Not Works

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I am trying to implement form validation in CodeIgniter. Please tell me what is my error. My problem is that it is always redirecting to error page, and even if I filled all details in html form, the validations are not working, means details are not entering into database.
View page code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>REGISTRATION</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url();?>Test/studentinsert" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
<label>Age</label>
<input type="number" name="age" id="age"><br>
<label>Address</label>
<textarea name="address" id="address"></textarea><br>
<label>User Name</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"><br>
<label>Password</label>
<input type="Password" name="Password" id="Password"><br>
<label>Gender</label>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female<br>
<label>Qqualifiction</label>
<input type="text" name="quali" id="quali"><br>
<input type="file" name="certificate" id="certificate"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">

</form>
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>Test/login">LOGIN</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Controller Page Code

```
public function studentinsert()
    {
        //$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'age', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('address', 'address', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender', 'gender', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('quali', 'quali', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('certificate', 'certificate', 'required');
        $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/';
        $config['allowed_types']        = '*';
        //$config['max_size']             = 100;
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        //$this->load->initialize($config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('certificate');
        $file="uploads/".$this->upload->data('file_name');
        $name=$this->input->post('name');
        $userid=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
        $age=$this->input->post('age');
        $address=$this->input->post('address');
        $gender=$this->input->post('gender');
        $username=$this->input->post('username');
        $hashpassword=hash('md5',$this->input->post('Password'));
        $quali=$this->input->post('quali');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
                {
                        $this->load->view('registration');
                }
         else{
        $data=array('file'=>$file,'userid'=>$userid,'name'=>$name,'age'=>$age,'address'=>$address,'gender'=>$gender,'quali'=>$quali,);
        $logdata=array('userid'=>$userid,'username'=>$username,'Password'=>$hashpassword);
        $ok=$this->modeldata->insertdb($data);
        $ok1=$this->modeldata->insertlogin($logdata);
        if($ok=="success")
        {
            $this->load->view('registration');
        }
}

    }
```

I had already loaded helper(form, url, form validation) class in controller in construct function and code is as follows

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('modeldata');
    // Load url helper
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

}
```

Comment: Where are your form validation rules? There is no magic. The form validation class needs rules to run.

Comment: i added validation rules too.But its not working.The data's are no entering into the database.

Comment: Is the value of $data what you expect it to be right before you pass it to the model? Do print_r( $data ); right before $this->modeldata->insertdb($data);

Comment: Yes...I got the exact value.When i filled all of the fields.

Comment: That means your problem is in modeldata->insertdb(). Since you haven't provided that, and don't know what your DB table looks like, I really can't advise you what to do.

Comment: Just a tip don't use Md5 for password not secure these days use php http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php to create and to verify use http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified the code to this

```
public function studentinsert(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules([
        [
            'field' => 'name',
            'label' => 'Name',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],[
            'field' => 'age',
            'label' => 'age',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],[
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'username',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],[
            'field' => 'password',
            'label' => 'password',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ],[
            'field' => 'quali',
            'label' => 'quali',
            'rules' => 'required'
        ]
    ]);
    $this->load->library('upload',[
        'upload_path' => './uploads/',
        'allowed_types'=> '*'
    ]);
    $this->upload->do_upload('certificate');
    $file="uploads/".$this->upload->data('file_name');
    $userid=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $name=$this->input->post('name');
    $userid=mt_rand(100000, 999999);
    $age=$this->input->post('age');
    $address=$this->input->post('address');
    $gender=$this->input->post('gender');
    $username=$this->input->post('username');
    $hashpassword=hash('md5',$this->input->post('Password'));
    $quali=$this->input->post('quali');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
         $this->load->view('registration');
    }else{
        $data=array('file'=>$file,'userid'=>$userid,'name'=>$name,'age'=>$age,'address'=>$address,'gender'=>$gender,'quali'=>$quali,);
        $logdata=array('userid'=>$userid,'username'=>$username,'Password'=>$hashpassword);
        $ok=$this->modeldata->insertdb($data);
        $ok1=$this->modeldata->insertlogin($logdata);
        if($ok=="success"){
            $this->load->view('registration');
        }
    }

}
```

You have a validation rule set for `certificate` and codeigniter assumed there is a `$_POST['certificate']` (which doesnt exist but `$_FILES['certificate']` does)
remove the `$this->form_validation->set_rules('certificate', 'certificate', 'required');` rule and use `isset($_FILES['certificate'])` instead. and then maybe redirect to error page if it isnt found

Comment: His problem is actually in the model, and so it was sort of a bad question, because he never did enough debugging to know what the real problem was.